# How to insert some data to database by clicking on telegram inline keyboard?

Tags: php, mysql, keyboard, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to insert some data to database using MySql and PHP when i click on telegram bot inline keyboard. But i now just can use URL and Alert Messages for inline keyboard. How can I insert some information to database by clicking on telegram inline keyboard?

Link: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CallbackQuery`for this.

1. Create a `InlineKeyboardButton` with `callback_data`
2. Catch `CallbackQuery` object via Webhook